# Warning: require_once(HTML/Common.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\php\pear\Table.php on line 68

Tags: php, xampp

i am a newbie to php, i am trying to install a pmb open source software on XamPP servers but i keep getting the error message

> Warning: require_once(HTML/Common.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in C:\xampp\php\pear\Table.php on line 68

Please help out!!

Comment: It can't find the `HTML/Common.php` What is your folder/file structure?

Comment: I am not very sure with what you mean by my file structure, but the PMB folder was extracted to the htdocs folder of xampp

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I faced the same error now the answer to the question is that we created a file with the name of `table.php` just change the name of that file it will work fine thank's.
This will not work because according to me in XAMMP there is also a file name `Table.php` in the following `directory XAMMP/php/pear/Table.php` so instead of reading or processing this file our website start reading or processing this file which will cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

Go this xampp installed folder change file name Table.php to any file like 2table.php

C:\xampp\php\pear\Table.php

Its Works for mee